# How can I implement a RESTful API in Drupal?

Tags: 8

Can any one please let me know what modules are available to implement a REST API?

So far I've only found the [Redmine REST API module](https://drupal.org/project/redmine_rest_api), which is used for Redmine.

Answer (score 2):

For a REST API implementation on Drupal, use the [Services](https://drupal.org/project/services) module.

> A standardized solution of integrating external applications with Drupal. Service callbacks may be used with multiple interfaces like REST, XMLRPC, JSON, JSON-RPC, SOAP, AMF, etc. This allows a Drupal site to provide web services via multiple interfaces while using the same callback code.

Comment: Hope you don't mind, I edited the question to clarify the Drupal aspect so the first part of your answer became a bit confusing - I edited it out. If you want to roll it back that's absolutely fine